# How does the "display: contents" property value work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm working with the `display:contents` property value paired with an `element > element` selector. [According to W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp), the `display: contents` property value

> Makes the container disappear, **making the child elements children of the element the next level up in the DOM**

(emphasis mine).

So I have this example code:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: contents;
}

.wrapper > .child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='hidden'>
    <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
    <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
  </div>

  <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
  <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
</div>
```

I was expecting to have all the children with yellow background, because the `element> element` selector should target them all (they are all at the same level when the property `display: contents` comes into play).

Why is this not the case? Is the CSS unable to target children in this way?

Comment: CSS selector only consider DOM structure without the CSS applied to it. Same logic if you use `display:none` on an element (ex: https://jsfiddle.net/gca6bm9y/) so this is a logical and expected result

Comment: Check here for an explanation: https://bitsofco.de/how-display-contents-works/ basically it doesn't take out the element, but instead _only_ shows the element's content (textnode, children). Also no, it doesn't apply to other CSS rules

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the **official** CSSWG [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#box-generation):

> **contents**
>
> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and pseudo-elements still generate [boxes](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#box) and text runs as normal. For the purposes of box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had been replaced in the element tree by its contents (including both its source-document children and its pseudo-elements, such as ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, which are generated before/after the element’s children as normal).
>
> > Note: As only the box tree is affected, **any semantics based on the document tree, such as selector-matching, event handling, and property inheritance, are not affected**. [...]

The bold part (emphasis mine) is the answer you are looking for.

Also note the phrase: "*must be treated as if it had been replaced in the element tree by its contents*". So the element isn't really removed, but to make it easier to explain, it's *like* the element is removed and replaced by its content.

---

PS: avoid the use of [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) as an official reference for accurate definitions like this. They can be good for explaining things in general, but will often fail to give precise and accurate definitions.

Comment: How does it work with `display: grid` on the parent?

Comment: @connexo what do you mean ?

Comment: As long as we don't use sub-grid, grid container definitions apply to direct children only. What if these have `display: content`? Will this kind of work like a sub-grid?

Comment: @connexo yes it behaves like sub-grid, here is a recent example where I used that technique: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73050415/8620333

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Temani Afif's answer, here's a visualization of what the box subtree for your element looks like with `display: contents` on `.hidden`:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <!-- <div class='hidden'> -->
    <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
    <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
  <!-- </div> -->

    <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
    <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
</div>
```

And here's a side-by-side comparison of two other elements, one of whose middle-layer element is `.hidden`:

```css
div { padding: 1em; }
.wrapper { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; background-color: red; margin: 1em; }
.wrapper > div { background-color: orange; }
.hidden { display: contents }
.child { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='hidden'>
    <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
    <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <div>
    <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
    <div class='child'>I'm a child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Indeed, it's rendered as though `.hidden` itself wasn't there (represented by being "commented out" in the pseudocode) and its own children were instead children of `.wrapper` (and in turn siblings of `.wrapper`'s own children). That's essentially what `display: contents` means.

Comment: This example doesn't seem clear to me; I think it would lead someone who doesn't understand the property to think it works exactly how OP expects it to work. One would need to understand that the box tree is separate from the full document tree parsing/selector-matching, in which case this just seems like reiterating Temani's answer. It could be improved by showing an emphasized counter example of what the CSS "sees".

Comment: @TylerH: OK, I've just tried two things: adding the .hidden element commented out to the pseudo-markup, and adding a snippet with a side-by-side comparison. I can't think of anything better because I don't think the side-by-side works very well either. Maybe simply using a tree of class names instead of pseudo-markup?