# Alternating row colors with css grid when using display:contents for the row wrapper

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to color every second row in my CSS grid but can't seem to figure this one out.

My html for the grid looks like this:

```
<div class="ingredientAreaWrapper">
  <div class="singleIngridientWrapper">
    <div class="amount cell"></div>
    <div class="unit cell"></div> 
    <div class="ingredient cell"></div>
    <div class="ingredientDetails cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS grid is setup like this:

```
.ingredientAreaWrapper{

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) 1fr 4fr 6fr;
    row-gap: 0.5rem;

}

.singleIngridientWrapper{
    display: contents;     
}
```

I have tried things like this after searching online in order to select every four cells in the grid, but I can't seem to get the selector right:

```
   .ingredientAreaWrapper > .cell:nth-child(4n + 1),
   .ingredientAreaWrapper > .cell:nth-child(4n + 2),
   .ingredientAreaWrapper > .cell:nth-child(4n + 3),
   .ingredientAreaWrapper > .cell:nth-child(4n + 4) {
     background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   }
```

How would you color every second grid row in a situation like this?

Comment: remove the `>` . related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55922178/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, you are right that the > shouldn't be there. But it still selects all of my .cells for the color instead four selected and then four not selected.

Comment: you are selecting all the four (+1 ,+2, +3, +4) keep only the one you want to select

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want to select every second row, and each row has four columns. So don't I have to select cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4 and the cell9 cell10 cell11 cell12 etc?

Comment: so it's not 4n but 8n

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried changing it to 8n but it still selects every single div. I think there is something else wrong with my selector. It seems to select all the div no matter what the numbers are in the nth-child formula.

Comment: it's related to a missundertanding of display:contents ... it doesn't affect the selector like you may think, (check the duplicates)

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's what I think too. But I can't seem to figure this one out, I have been trying tons of variations for the selector without luck. I think I will try to get rid of the display:contents wrapper.

Comment: try this one instead `.ingredientAreaWrapper > div:nth-child(2n + 1) .cell { }`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Incredible selector! That one worked! Thank you so much!