# position: sticky not working after some amount of scroll

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am trying to create a layout where 1st and last columns in a `div` are sticky. When I scroll for some amount, the left most column goes beyond left limit. Why could this be happening and how do I fix it?

When you scroll to the very right, you can see that red column goes out of the box.

Sample codepen: https://codepen.io/vighnesh-google/pen/WNzjvqN

Sample code:

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header,
.body {
 display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.sticky-item-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;  
  background: red;
}

.sticky-item-right {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="item sticky-item-left"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item sticky-item-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="item sticky-item-left"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item sticky-item-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That "some amount" appears to not be arbitrary, but exactly 100% of the viewport width.

Comment: @CBroe more precisely it's the width of the containing block of the sticky element (add border to header/body to see it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to solve this:

```css
.slider {
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid; /* main element as grid */
  grid-auto-columns: 20%;  /* width of the items */
}
.header,
.body {
   display: contents; /* remove the parent boundary to make sticky works */
}
.header > * {
  grid-row: 1; /* all header elements in first row */
}
.body > * {
  grid-row: 2; /* all body elements in second row */
}
.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.sticky-item-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;  
  background: red;
}

.sticky-item-right {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="item sticky-item-left"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item sticky-item-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="item sticky-item-left"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item sticky-item-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To understand the issue with your initial code, add border to the parent element to see the limit of the sticky elements:

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header,
.body {
 display: flex;
 border:4px solid blue;
}

.item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.sticky-item-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;  
  background: red;
}

.sticky-item-right {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="item sticky-item-left"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item sticky-item-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="item sticky-item-left"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item sticky-item-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use of `display: contents` for this is a very nifty trick! :-)

Comment: This is perfect and works. In the flex approach, I am still not clear why the first column goes beyond the limit. I mean, there are elements in the row to be scrolled, so, I thought it would stick to the left, until we run out of elements to scroll or until the parent's left + element size is less than parent's right.

Comment: @VighneshRaut check the last demo I added to understand. A flex item is limited by its parent boundary and your items are overflowing their parent since they are defined as percentage.

Comment: Aaah. So, because of `display: flex` on parent, the "position: sticky" with "position: relative" grandparent is not respected once the parent goes out of view.

Comment: @VighneshRaut relative and flex has nothing to do here. It's all about the boundaries. If you make your items 20% of their parent you will have an overflow after 5 items because, for example, 10*20% = 200% is bigger than 100% (the parent width) so you will always have an overflow and a sticky element is limited to the parent boundary

Comment: Gotcha. I assumed that sticky element is limited by closest "position: relative" parent. Thanks for clarifying. 

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in the fact that all the items stacked next to each other become larger than the div they are placed in. Therefore they overflow the div and you end up actually scrolling the div off of the screen.

A simple solution is add `overflow: scroll;` to both the header and body class by updating the CSS to the following:

```
.header,
.body {
 display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

For further reading on the topic, have a look at [Css Tricks:Creating sliding effects using sticky positioning](https://css-tricks.com/creating-sliding-effects-using-sticky-positioning/)

Comment: Yea. This could work. But was avoiding to do this because I want to scroll all the rows together, and not single row independently, without using JS.